# Error whith ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, node-modules

I'm having this error with Ionic 3 for any command I launch even `ionic -v`

> Error
>       at FatalException.Exception (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/dist/lib/errors.js:8:23)
>       at FatalException (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/dist/lib/errors.js:17:9)
>       at Config. (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/dist/lib/config.js:60:35)
>       at throw (native)
>       at rejected (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/dist/lib/config.js:5:65)
>   name: 'Exception', exitCode: 1, fatal: true

I tried uninstalling ionic then reinstalling but the error persisted.

Any help or recommendation would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `ionic config.json` file, great chance it is empty or corrupt based on this error.  To get to the file location do the following.

Open up your terminal and go to your root directory

`cd /`

Next get to the `.ionic` folder.

`cd Users/<User>/.ionic`

Once here check the `config.json` to see its contents.  Like I said it is most likely empty or corrupt so go ahead and delete it, then reinstall Ionic and that should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try npm prune which removes unnecessary node file relative to you project

If all else fails then rm -rf node_modules then npm install(be careful with this as it clears all npm data)

Answer (score 0):

delete node_module folder and re-run npm install command , it works .